# Problem with green screen on PS3 after freeze

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

I have a backwards compatible PS3, and I know they're finicky as all heck. But I was playing on it just fine when the screen froze (nothing I'm not used to). Restarted the PlayStation like normal. No problem. The screen turns on... and it's green! I turn it off, give it a while, and turn it back on.
It turns on fine, doesn't beep at me when I turn it on, so it's not signalling anything is wrong.

However, now my PS3 doesn't put out or receive any input!
My controller won't turn it on (no, the batteries aren't dead). I have tried plugging it in. The controller doesn't even register the PS3! The cord I use works. I've used that cord multiple times and have been using it whenever the PS3 was having problems to begin with.

The HDMI isn't putting out any input to the TV either. And before you say "make sure it's in the right HDMI port": it is (HDMI port 2).

Does anyone have any clue about what's wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Also! Before someone says something about the res. Its not the resolution again i was olaying on it literally 10 minutes ago just fine. It simply just wknt put out ANY input.

Comment: It looks to me graphic board is (almost) dead. Unless you're Sony's engineer and have spare board, you have no way to fix it on your own. Send it to Sony if they still accepts it.

Comment: If it is not an hardware failure the only thing that comes to mind is trying safe mode and rebuild the database. But be aware that could end up erasing your data (saves etc) if they are found corrupted